# Probability that leading Eigenvalue is real

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

What is the probability that the leading Eigenvalue (largest real part) of a large i.i.d Gaussian (real) random matrix is real? To what will this probability converge in the limit of large size?

Update: my numerical experiments find that the fraction of leading eigenvalues that are real drops with size but appears to saturate somewhere around 0.3. I calculated this for matrices up to N=8000, albeit for only 80 realizations each.

Comment: to be clear, you are talking about real matrices, right?

Comment: @nbubis yes, I'm talking about matrices with real entries

Comment: @loupblanc Pardon me for not updating the post with the results of my simulations.

Comment: @idl: I have exactly the same question (for the same definition of "leading" eigenvalue). Were you able to find an answer to it?

Comment: @shawarma474, I never did get an answer.

Answer (score 7):

These matrices are known as (real) Ginibre ensembles.

The following [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aoap/1400073659)<sup>1</sup> proves that the limit is actually zero, and not one:

> "To make this explicit, we check here that the probability of the
>   largest point in absolute value being real tends to zero."

They also show this to be true experimentally (diagram taken from their paper):
[image]

And adding regarding your assumption:

> The striking feature is the so-called “Saturn effect,” based on which
>   alone a person might be forgiven for having conjectured that the
>   largest eigenvalue would be real, with probability one, as
>   $n\to\infty$. Rather, the Saturn effect is a phenomenon which appears
>   from plotting the eigenvalues of many matrices simultaneously.
>   Eventually, the complex points overwhelm the $O(\sqrt{n})$ on the real
>   line.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>*Extremal laws for the real Ginibre ensemble* Brian Rider and Christopher D. Sinclair</sub>

Comment: The reason that I would guess the probability to be at least Order 1 in the large N limit is because the leading Eigenvalue will have real part closer and closer to 1 as N grows so that the relative probability density of having non-zero imaginary part eventually shrinks in the large N limit.

Comment: @idl - Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks nbubis, but I believe you misread that sentence. They are saying there that the Eigenvalue of largest **absolute value ** will be real with probability zero. I'm pretty sure they say they don't know about the eigenvalue with largest real part (which is what I meant by Leading Eigenvalue, maybe that was an ambiguous phrase to use -- in the context of continuous dynamics it's the one with largest real part that is called Leading).

Comment: @idl - Oh! Yes, I did think you meant largest absolute value. I think this result still holds though, but I have to think about how to prove it.

Comment: @nbus, so looking more closely in the paper you cited I find that they discuss the distribution on the largest real eigenvalue, and a paper by Poplavsky, Tribe, Zaboronski 2016 prove that this distribution has Gaussian right tail, and Exponential left tail. It looks like both directions effectively have typical deviation of 1/sqrt(N) when the eigenvalues are scaled to the unit disk. In order to answer my question I now would need to calculate the conditional probability that there is a complex eigenvalue larger than this largest real eigenvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this probability is also converging to zero, albeit very slowly. Here is a summary of the results.
For an $n \times n$ real Ginibre ensemble, the following asymptotic hold

1. Largest real eigenvalue: $\max|\lambda_{\mathbb{R}}| \sim \sqrt n$
2. Largest modulus: $\max|\lambda|\sim \sqrt n + \sqrt {\frac{\log n} {4}}$
3. Largest real part: $\max\mathfrak{Re}(\lambda)\sim\sqrt n + \sqrt {\frac{\log n}{8}}$
   In particular, this indicates that the eigenvalue with the largest real part will not be be the largest real eigenvalue.

These results are summarized quite well in the following reference:

[Giorgio Cipolloni, László Erdős, Dominik Schröder, Yuanyuan Xu; Directional extremal statistics for Ginibre eigenvalues. J. Math. Phys. 1 October 2022; 63 (10): 103303](https://doi.org/10.1063/5.0104290)

Comment: Nice! That's a good find. How large are the Tracy-Widom fluctuations in this scaling though? Are they not larger than O(1)?